# Kafka Conenct HDFS sink saving data in parquet format

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Using Kafka Connect HDFS Sink I am able to write avro data to Kafka topic and save data in hive/hdfs.
I am trying to save data in parquet file format using format class

```
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat
```

quickstart-hdfs.properties are as follows

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test_hdfs_parquet
hdfs.url=hdfs://localhost:9000
flush.size=3
hive.metastore.uris=thrift://10.15.167.109:9083
hive.integration=true
schema.compatibility=BACKWARD
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner
locale=en-us
timezone=UTC
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat
```

When I post data to Kafka, Table is created in hive, test_hdfs_parquet directory created in hdfs but Sink is Unable to save data in parquet format due to the following exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema.getLogicalType()Lorg/apache/avro/LogicalType;
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:178)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:130)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:227)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertFields(AvroSchemaConverter.java:124)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:115)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.writeSupport(AvroParquetWriter.java:144)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:106)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetRecordWriterProvider$1.write(ParquetRecordWriterProvider.java:68)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter.writeRecord(TopicPartitionWriter.java:635)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:379)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.write(DataWriter.java:374)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.put(HdfsSinkTask.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2018-03-13 11:48:41,148] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:517)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What version of Connect are you using? Are you running Confluent Platform, or only using HDFS Connect directly from Github?

Comment: Downloaded confluent from link https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html, Version of Confluent is 4.0.0

Comment: Hmm. Haven't tried Parquet format personally, but the error is actually in the Avro libraries

Comment: There is a conflict of avro version used in hive-exec jar parquet-avro jar. Downgrading version of parquet-avro jar from parquet-avro-1.8.2.jar to parquet-avro-1.7.0.jar solved my problem. Not sure whether this is the proper way of resolving the issue

Comment: Hmm. Would you like to make an issue on Github? https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues What made you choose 1.7.0?

Comment: I just randomly picked a version which is lower than the version used in hive-exec jar

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be running into [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues/261)

[The solution mentioned](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/pull/50) is using Avro 1.7.7 libraries, which means not just `parquet-avro`, but also the other avro jars.

Or you could try to compile hdfs-connect from source, and update all the jars.